# Can an event listener call a function from inside another function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can this be done ??

```
stage.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, finish);

private function new(e:TouchEvent):void {

     function finish(e:TouchEvent):void {


     }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, strille is right, your finish() function should reside outside new() function. The variables you want to transfer can be stored in your object's properties, then you refer to them within your finish() function. Also, I wouldn't dare naming your function "new", as it already has a meaning in Actionscript 3.

```
private function newTouch(e:TouchEvent):void {
    touchedAtX=e.localX;
    touchedAtY=e.localY;
    // store more if you want to
}

private function finish(e:TouchEvent):void {
    // here you can use your touchedAtX and touchedAtY stored values, 
    // as well as anything else
}
```

Comment: new was just an example, but i think this will get me round my problem thanks

Comment: ok does this still work of newTouch was Event and finish was TouchEvent ?

Comment: The base principle works, but plain Event class does not have properties like "localX" "localY". MouseEvent does have these, though. Check what you are actually listening to, and check manuals for available event properties.

Answer (score 0):

No, the inner finish() function is not available/visible outside of the outer new() function. The question is why finish() needs to be defined in new(), and can't reside outside of it?

```
private function new(e:TouchEvent):void {
   finish(e);
}

private function finish(e:TouchEvent):void {

}
```

Comment: new is run on touch down, finish is run on touch up but i have variables in new i want to us within finish